# Is it safe to charge a LiPo battery with a Li-ion battery charger circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, lithium-ion, charger

My PCB includes Li-ion charger (3.7 V) circuit with BQ25060. BQ25060 is to charge single Li-ion battery according to datasheet.

I bought new LiPo battery (1S, 3.7 V, 1550 mAh) but, there is not information about LiPo battery in BQ25060 datasheet.

Is it safe to charge a LiPo battery with a Li-ion battery charger circuit?
If I can't charge, can someone explain why?

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25060.pdf?ts=1619636089137&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended upper voltage limit is 4.2V for Li-Ion (including "Li-Po"). One also needs to ensure that the current is appropriate for the battery's capacity. The recommended charge rate for Li-ion is ~0.5C, meaning that a battery with a capacity of X Amp-hours should be charged at X Amp / 2 (or less). The datasheet for your charging chip shows a maximum programmable output current of 1 Amp, which is more than the maximum permitted for your 1.55 Amp-hour battery.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understood that Recommended charge current should be 1.55 Amp. But, it wouldn't be a big problem If if I charge it longer time with 1 A, right? Or, Should I buy new lipo battery 1000mAh ? @FrontRanger

Comment: Correct. Also, some batteries are overrated on capacity, so 1A on your nominally-1.55 Amp-hour battery gives you some safety margin and is not far from optimal.